# Place DIV element next to SPAN element inside parent TD

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to place a div element next a span element inside parent .

Currently  element is getting display belove the span element. I need it to display next to span element.

Here is HTML structure I am using:

```
<td>
  <a align="right"><img></a>
  <a align="right"><img></a>
  <img>
  <a><img></a>
  <span id="labelSpan">test</span>
  <div id="headerDiv" style="margin-left:150px;">
    <table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
  </div>
</td>
```

An additional requirement is that I need to set margin of div element with respect to parent td element not span element.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: user1913544 In the future, please post the actual code and not an image. (Thanks for typing it out kunalbhat.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
div {
    display: inline;
}
```

This will make the div an inline element like the span and the two will sit side by side. You'll probably need to change the display of the table as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make the span `display-inline`. This will place it next to the div. Or make it display:block and then float the span. (float:left;)

```
 span {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make `span` a block level element.

**Example**

```
span {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do *three* things: Set display of the `<span>` and the `<div>` to `inline-block`. This will ensure that they are both on the same line. Then *remove* the margin from the `<div>`. Finally add a `width` to the `<span>`. Now the `<div>` is exactly *150px* away from the left side of the `<td>`.

```
td > span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
td > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/gG8mm/)